how to access the cookie in express.js
enter image description hereI am trying to access a cookie I set after logging in with JWT. However, instead of receiving the cookie, I get [Object: null prototype] {}. I have already installed cookie-parser. How can I resolve this issue?
How can I properly access the cookie on the server-side in my Express application?

Show code where you are getting error.

trying to get cookie insted of cookie i get cookie i got this [Object: null prototype] {}

Please show code where you have configured cookie in script i.e. share the code where you set cookie after Logging in with JWT

its not error its not getting me cookie its giving me this insetad of cookie [Object: null prototype] {

You will get better help if you post the relevant codes as well. As you know, every post is supposed to have a "minimal reproducible example" . This will help the contributors to quickly come to your issue and extend their best help.

@SheshraoSuryawanshi, If you don't share code block regarding cookie i.e how you configure it & how did you access it, nobody can help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
